# Use Facebook friends list in my app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am wanting to create a small social network app and I was wondering if the following is possible?

I want users to log into the app using their facebook username and password

The app will then get the users facebook friend list and check if any of his friends are using the app right now

For the users friends that are using the app, they will show up as active in the app

If the user has no friends using the app there will be an option to invite Facebook friends to join the app.

I am wondering if this would be possible? if so could someone please briefly outline what I would need to do or what sdk's I would need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t use username/password to log into your App. You need to implement authorization: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

You can´t get ALL friends anymore, only those who authorized your App too. More information can be found in this thread: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

About inviting friends to an App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app